# Why in module inequality $|f(x)| < A$ with a positive A we do not explicitly check that $f(x)>=0$ and $f(x)<0$?

Tags: inequality, education

$|f(x)| < A$ when $А > 0$ is equivalent to the following system:

$$\begin{cases}
f(x) < A  \\  
f(x) > -A \\ 
\end{cases}
$$

Sorry to ask this, but I do not completely understand, why we do not exclude those $x$, for which $f(x)<0$ in the first equation, and $x$ for which $f(x)<0$ in the second equation - I mean why we do not write explicitly two systems of inequalities, uniting their solutions like this:

$$\begin{cases}
f(x) < A  \\  
f(x) >= 0 \\ 
\end{cases}
$$

$$\begin{cases}
f(x) > -A \\ 
f(x) < 0 \\ 
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: The combination of the two system below is just the system above. We tend to use the "simplest" notation.

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The two systems are completely equivalent.

In the first you find directly all solutions by intersection of two inequalities, in the second case by union of two different systems of inequalities.